# JPA with dyanmic query also dyamic(optinal) paramters in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpql, persistent

I am new in Hibernate
This is my JPA/Hibernate query with multiple left join so, I want know How write query in JPA.  Parameters is optional may change one/two/three parameter.
I want order may be null or Animal,dosage,cassete_code also add filter is Map elements.

e.g. where s.study_fk=2 order by dosage,animal and dosage="High"/animal=104/organ="liver".

But this parameters are optinal...

```
SELECT d.level, s.slide_pk from slideimage s
LEFT JOIN studyanimal a ON s.animal_fk=a.animal_pk
LEFT JOIN study_dosage sd ON a.study_dos_fk=sd.study_dos_pk
LEFT JOIN dosage d ON sd.dosage_fk=d.dosage_pk
where s.study_fk=2 order by d.level;
```

I am stuck here please help me guys.  (Sorry for bad english.)

Answer (score 0):

If you've written your entity correctly (@OneToMany relationships), you simply have to select the top level entity itself.

E.g.

```
SELECT s FROM SlideImage s
LEFT JOIN s.studyAnimal a
LEFT JOIN a.studyDosage sd
LEFT JOIN sd.dosage d
WHERE s.study = ?1
```

Will result in a collection of SlideImage entites with their nested attributes populated.